# Replacing hole punched/STUN UDP socket with TCP socket at runtime

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, stun

I have a situation where I used STUN to establish a UDP [RTP] connection between two clients so that they can stream media with one another with some packet loss. Now, they are done streaming media and one client would like to send the other client a large file. Rather than using UDP [RTP] to send the large file, I would find it more convenient, as a programmer, to send the file with TCP because TCP takes care of re-sending lost packets on my behalf. Can I just tell the client applications to stop using their UDP connections (say with "socket.close(); socket = null;") and immediately open up new TCP connections at the same port/address as the UDP connections? Will that work or will the three-way handshake get blocked? Is there a timing or security issue involved? In which cases will replacing hole punched UDP with TCP work and in which cases will it not work?

Comment: You can use STUN to help establish TCP connections between devices that are behind NATs.  Although it is slightly more tricky and not as reliable as UDP.  (Hint, both sides have to connect to each other simultaneously).  Shameless plug: [Stuntman](http://www.stunprotocol.org) supports TCP STUN.

Answer (score 1):

`TCP` and `UDP` ports are different. A `TCP` socket at port 1000, is a completely different communication endpoint from a `UDP` socket at port 1000. So your application could just span a new thread, establish a new `TCP` connection and transfer the desired file. The `UDP` connection can continue the exchange of `RTP` packets.

Comment: Oh. So I can't swap a UDP port for a TCP port and vice versa. But I can swap a UDP port for the same UDP port on another process to allow another process to use that UDP port. Can I swap a TCP port on one process with an identical # TCP port on another process or pass active TCP connections between processes, perhaps via shared memory or by serializing the Java TCP socket?

Comment: On the same host computer you can NOT use the same port in more than one open socket, regardless the protocol (`TCP`, `UDP`). Sorry but perhaps I do not understand the term "swap". If you want to transfer the file, one of the end hosts should open a `TCP` socket on a specific port known to both sides. The other host connects to this `TCP` port and initiate the transfer.